# How to copy local vm files to azure builder vm in packer build

Tags: azure-devops, ansible, packer, ansible-template, packer-builder

I am new to Packer + Ansible combination example. Below is my provisioner which is calling ansible yml file using Azure builder,

```
"provisioners": [
        {
            "execute_command": "chmod +x {{ .Path }}; {{ .Vars }} sudo -E sh '{{ .Path }}'",
            "inline": [
                "sudo yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-$(rpm -E '%{rhel}').noarch.rpm",
                "sudo yum -y install ansible"
            ],
            "inline_shebang": "/bin/sh -x",
            "type": "shell"
        },
        {
            "type": "ansible-local",
            "playbook_file": "/tmp/app.yml"
        }
    ]
```

In my app.yml, I want to copy my script to temporary vm (pkr* ) that gets created at the time of `packer build` run. So /tmp/script.sh will be executed. However I am not getting exact module to be used to copy file from local(/tmp/script.sh) to packer builder vm.

app.yml

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: copy script from local to vm
    ansible.builtin.template:
      src: /tmp/script.sh
      dest: /tmp/
  - name: validate copied files
    command: ls /tmp
  - copy:
      src: /tmp/script.sh
      dest: /tmp/
  - command: ls /tmp/
  - script: /tmp/script.sh
```

Error :

```
azure-arm: TASK [copy script from local to vm] ****************************************
    azure-arm: fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not find or access '/tmp/script.sh' on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are usin
g a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"}
```

I have tried both **copy** and **ansible.builtin.template** modules, but no luck.

Comment: the error is clear:  your file script.sh is not found...your file exists on ansible server master?

Comment: @Frenchy But it is present in my local machine. However, when packer build creates new environment for building the image. It is checking in that new VM ( usually starts with pkr ) which is not present. Now I want to copy it before ansible module run.

Comment: You can use below code, 
``` {
            "type": "file",
            "source": "/your/path",
            "destination": "/tmp/"
        } 
{
            "type": "ansible-local",
            "playbook_file": "app.yml"
        } ```